# Which Delphi component contains the most events?

Tags: delphi, events, components

I was writing some code a few days ago based on Hallvard's [Hack #10](http://hallvards.blogspot.com/2006/05/hack-10-getting-parameters-of.html), and it made me wonder, how many events tend to get put on things?  So far, the highest count I've found comes from an in-house custom descendant of a DevExpress grid at the company I work for, which has 83 published events in the Object Inspector.  Anyone know a component that can top that?

Answer (score 4):

[`TVirtualStringTree`](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=12&Itemid=33) has 100 published event properties in version 4.7.0, in addition to whatever events are published in its ancestors. Its cousin, `TVirtualDrawTree`, has 97.

Answer (score 0):

This is really an unanswerable question since whatever number is come up with here could easily be topped tomorrow.  Unless there is an upper limit to the number of published events a component can have, there is no answer.  As soon as one is agreed on then someone could release on that has N+1 events.  Repeat forever.

Comment: I suppose.  This is really just a "just for fun" sort of question anyway.

Comment: I fail to see the relevance of questions as this on a software developers forum site.